# How to fix this error while setting up laravel-mix?

Tags: node.js, laravel, npm, sass, bootstrap-modal

I'm new to Laravel. I use Laravel version 5.4 and this is my `package.json` file

```json
{
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "npm run development",
    "development": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
    "watch": "npm run development -- --watch",
    "watch-poll": "npm run watch -- --watch-poll",
    "hot": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js --inline --hot --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
    "prod": "npm run production",
    "production": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --no-progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.18",
    "bootstrap": "^4.0.0",
    "popper.js": "^1.12",
    "cross-env": "^5.1",
    "jquery": "^3.2",
    "laravel-mix": "^2.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.4",
    "vue": "^2.5.7"
  }
}
```

Running `npm install` in my command prompt in windows, shows this error:

> ```
> node-sass@4.9.0 install C:\wamp1\www\Project\node_modules\node-sass                           
>
> node scripts/install.js                                                                                                           
>
> Downloading binary from https://github.com/sass/node-sass/releases/download/v4.9.0/win32-ia32-57_binding.node
>
> assert.js:42                                                                                                                        
>   throw new errors.AssertionError({                                                                                                 
>   ^                                                                                                                                 
>
> AssertionError [ERR_ASSERTION]: 6111 == 0                                                                                           
>     at ClientRequest.onConnect (C:\wamp1\www\Project\node_modules\tunnel-agent\index.js:159:14)      
>
>     at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:319:30)                                                                                        
>     at emitThree (events.js:136:13)                                                                                                 
>     at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:217:7)                                                                                         
>     at Socket.socketOnData (_http_client.js:474:11)                                                                                 
>     at emitOne (events.js:116:13)                                                                                                   
>     at Socket.emit (events.js:211:7)                                                                                                
>     at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:263:12)                                                                                        
>     at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:250:11)                                                                                
>     at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:208:10)                                                                            
> npm WARN rollback Rolling back readable-stream@2.3.6 failed (this is probably harmless): EPERM: operation not permitted,            
>  lstat 'C:\wamp1\www\Project\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules'                                                                    
> npm WARN ajv-keywords@3.2.0 requires a peer of ajv@^6.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies your            
> self.                                                                                                                               
> npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.4 (node_modules\fsevents):                                             
> npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.4: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any            
> "} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"ia32"})                                                                                          
>
> npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE                                                                                                            
> npm ERR! errno 1                                                                                                                    
> npm ERR! node-sass@4.9.0 install: `node scripts/install.js`                                                                         
> npm ERR! Exit status 1                                                                                                              
> npm ERR!                                                                                                                            
> npm ERR! Failed at the node-sass@4.9.0 install script.                                                                              
> npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.                                  
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:                                                                                
> npm ERR!     C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2018-05-20T17_07_26_454Z-debug.log
> ```

I don't know what's wrong. I looked through the site for solution, however, I couldn't find one. Please do help

Comment: Please check your directory permissions for npm, cause in my Win10 installation, all went fine (although different architecture - x64 here). You can also add `"ajv": "^6.5.0"` to your devDependencies, cause as warnings said, you need to install it manually...